# Get word frequencies from a pretrained word2vec model in gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am trying to get the CBOW represention (word frequencies) out of a pretrained word2vec model in gensim. I know that the word2vec model I am using was originally trained using CBOW so the word2vec object must store word frequencies somewhere but I cannot find it. I did read the documentation but did not help at all, or maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Edit: If there's no way to retrieve the word frequencies except by having the original dataset, please tell me straight away.

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to do that without having the original dataset. Maybe there's a relationship between the cosine distance between a vector and its nearest neighbor and the frequency of a word, in the sense that if a word appears frequently, it is more important to give it a more distinct vector?

Comment: How did you receive the model & how are you loading it? (Not all sets of word-vectors will retain raw word frequencies, but even sets of vectors without word counts are usually stored in most-frequent to least-frequent order – so there'll still be hints of relative frequency.)